# splash page checkbox validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

So, I am working on a project for a recreational cannabis retailer. It's a splash page promotional website (one page, uses jQuery to fade into full screen video), and I have it pretty much all finished. You go to the URL, and are prompted to "ENTER" so long as you are of age.

The law here requires that we verify the person entering the site is aged 21+ via checkbox, which I have also accomplished, however now I can't figure out how to make my jQuery function execute correctly after the checkbox requirement is validated.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="splash">
    <div class="checkbox-group required">
        <Br />
        <form>
            <input type="checkbox" name="age" id="age" required>  I am 21 
years of age or older<Br /><Br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="alien" id="alien" required>  I am not an alien
            <input type="image" src="img/enter.png" id="enter">
        </form>
    </div>
    <img src="img/ufo2.jpg">
</div>
```

My JS:

```
    if(form.checkbox.checked) {
    $( "#enter" ).click(function() {
      $( "#splash" ).fadeOut( "slow" );
    });

    $( "#enter" ).click(function() {
      $( "#post-splash" ).fadeIn( "slow" );
    });
}
```

I've a feeling it has something to do with my event method but I'm not familiar enough with JS yet to crack it. Thanks!

Comment: When are you running the JS code that you posted?

Comment: @J.Chen After the html, but I've tested having it everywhere on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$( "#enter" ).click(function() {
    var ageCheck = $('#age').is(':checked');
    var alienCheck = $('#alien').is(':checked');
    if(ageCheck == true && alienCheck == true){
        $( "#splash" ).fadeOut( "slow" );
        $( "#post-splash" ).fadeIn( "slow" );

    }
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was going for! Except it's still not working for some reason. When you click "ENTER" the form just clears but the splash page doesn't fadeout like it's supposed to. Here is the URL if I'm not being clear:
http://dianeselvy.com/hah/

Comment: Wait, I fixed it! For some reason I the 'input' element wouldn't work with the jquery effects, but formatting it as just an img it works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen *click* event for target checkbox:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#age').click(function() {

    // Clicking checkbox will make it checked,
    // so checkbox check code goes here

    $("#enter").click(function() {
      $("#splash").fadeOut("slow");
      $("#post-splash").fadeIn("slow");
    });

    // Code moved to above
    /*
    $("#enter").click(function() {
      $("#post-splash").fadeIn("slow");
    });
    */
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="splash">
  <div class="checkbox-group required">
    <Br />
    <form>
      <input type="checkbox" name="age" id="age" required> I am 21 years of age or older
      <Br />
      <Br />
      <input type="checkbox" name="alien" id="alien" required> I am not an alien
      <input type="image" src="img/enter.png" id="enter">
    </form>
  </div>
  <img src="img/ufo2.jpg">
</div>
```